# WPF C# Recording Dependency object data modification

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Am working with dependency objects here, not done much with them before but they look very useful.

Basically I've used these objects to be editable in a ListView. However, I then have to write these changes back to SQL. My question is, is there a way to record whether the data has been modified because I don't want to write back to SQL every time someone views the data. Currently I have this:

```
public class KPI : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DepartmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Department", typeof(string), typeof(KPI), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Department
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DepartmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DepartmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty KPINumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("KPINumberProperty", typeof(int), typeof(KPI), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public int KPINumber
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(KPINumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KPINumberProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

My idea was to have something like:

```
    public static bool DataModified = false;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DepartmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Department", typeof(string), typeof(KPI), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public string Department
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(DepartmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DepartmentProperty, value); DataModified = true; }
    }
```

So every time something is edited the DataModified property will be set to TRUE, is this a good way of doing it? Or has somebody got a much better way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

SumGuy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF binding system doesn't *necessarily* call the `Department` CLR property, instead it directly calls `SetValue` whenever it updates dependency property (in this case `Department`). That means, your CLR wrapper may not get called, which in turns means whatever code you've written in `set` block (of `Department` CLR property) would not be executed.

But don't worry, there is solution for it. While initializing `DepartmentProperty` you can pass a callback to `UIPropertyMetadata` which would be called everytime it updates the dependency property. All it means is that, you've to implement this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DepartmentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
   (
       "Department", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(KPI), 
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnDepartmentChanged)
   );

public string Department
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DepartmentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DepartmentProperty, value);}
}

static void OnDepartmentChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     (d as KPI).DataModified  = true; //this is all you want!
}
```

Comment: In what case would the binding engine call the Department CLR property instead of calling SetValue directly?

Comment: @Robin: It's difficult to say; in some cases it might call CLR wrapper, in some cases it may directly call `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods.  Besides, CLR properties make intellisense to bring up the names in the XAML.

Comment: I agree that it is better practice to make the CLR properties, but I've just never seen or read about any time where the binding engine uses them instead of GetValue or SetValue. I'll take your word for it though.

Answer (score 4):

This actually won't work if you're binding to the dependency property. The WPF binding engine does not actually use your CLR "Department" property, but rather uses "SetValue" on the dependency property directly. There is an easy solution to this though.

The UIPropertyMetadata has a field for a PropertyChangedCallback which will fire every time the value of the property is changed (either from a call to SetValue directly, or through the CLR property which is wrapping the SetValue call)

Here's an example:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DepartmentProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("Department", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(KPI), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null, DepartmentPropertyChanged));

private static void DepartmentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    KPI me = d as KPI;
    if (me == null) return;

    // Talk to your Business/Data layers here
}    

public string Department
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DepartmentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DepartmentProperty, value); }
}
```

The DependencyObject (d) is the object who the property belongs to. In your case, this would be an instance of KPI.

For reference, here's a link to the UIPropertyMetadata MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uipropertymetadata.aspx